# Is there a Windows equivalent to the Linux "aplay" that will accept a bitstream and output audio?

Tags: windows, command-line, audio

I was watching [a Computerphile video about code golf and chiptunes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqZgoNRERY8) and was interested in running [the example code provided](http://txti.es/bitshiftvariationsincminor), but it relies on `aplay`, a Linux utility for the ALSA sound card driver, and I'd like to run this on Windows 7. Is there an equivalent program or utility on Windows 7+ (preferably but not necessarily OS-provided) that will take a stream of bytes and convert it to an audio stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same :)

I found you can use ffmpeg to convert it

```
ffmpeg -f u8 -i music.raw music.wav
```

Then use whatever you like to play it

Now, I tried piping it directly (vlc allows input on stdin, but it won't read raw data, at least not without arguments I'm not sure how to give it lol)

```
music.exe | ffmpeg ... -i pipe:1 | vlc.exe -
```

but ffmpeg said the pipe didn't have enough space (I tried pipe:0 as well since I wasn't 100% sure which it be for stdin on windows...)

so I ended up redirecting music.exe to a music.raw file for a small amount of time (`music.exe > music.raw`) then I could use this to pipe straight from ffmpeg to vlc

```
ffmpeg.exe -f u8 -i music.raw -f wav pipe:1 | vlc.exe -
```

Comment: This is as good an answer as any, so I'll mark it. I think the real answer is that there's no good direct pipe solution on windows

Comment: I'd like to comment this on yours but I don't have 50 rep :) 

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205107/generating-a-long-sound-file-with-sox-without-actually-playing-the-tone

I found the above with a google search so while the command may be a bit longer than `./a | aplay`, you could theoretically do so without having to save the file. You could then add the command to a makefile/batch file etc.

Comment: The main problem I've found with using play.exe from SoX is that it has a hard time interfacing with Windows sound drivers. Maybe I just don't know enough about SoX, but I haven't figured out yet how to get play.exe to work without just throwing an error

Comment: hm, the download I got for sox didn't actually have play.exe but I found that you can just specify an output of "-t -waveaudio default" instead of a file.

btw, I threw it all up on dropbox if you're interested: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ibb924waxkqga04/AAAa3yxp_lf7_awM2eY30bPqa?dl=0

Comment: you can duplicate sox.exe and rename it to play.exe and it will run with certain default options meant for playing sounds. in fact I think play.exe is the same as sox -t waveaudio default

Comment: I just found out that it actually works with ffmpeg if you do not specify a pipe number. Just type `a.exe | ffmpeg.exe -ar 8000 -f u8 -i pipe: -f wav pipe: | vlc.exe -` and you should be good to go. The option `-ar` sets the sample rate to 8000 Hz. By default ffmpeg uses 44100 Hz.

Comment: KenB: I agree with "the real answer is that there's no good direct pipe solution on windows".  This is a case of: Linux people develop a driver that converts audio bits to the data that the sound cards expect, then people are awestruck by this coolness and seek how Windows does this.  But that doesn't mean that this functionality is part of the finite features of what already exists built into Windows.  So, yes, a third party solution may be needed.  I suspect there might be a possibility using something like VBScript and objects, so less code is needed, but some extra code probably is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I watched exactly the same video and was very disappointed that I could not find a program for windows that behaves like aplay in this example.

In the end, I wrote one myself using C++ and [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/). I will post the code below. You will have to link to the OpenAL library to build the executable. The library is part of the OpenAL Core SDK which you can download from their website.

If you just want the executable, you can download it [here](https://cloud.gsc.ce.tu-darmstadt.de/index.php/s/Kyir0UEwpKej5pm). Look for `yalpa.exe`.

**Syntax**

Let's say you use my executable `yalpa.exe`. Then you can process your raw audio data by piping it to yalpa:

```
a.exe | yalpa.exe
```

Alternatively you could first write the audio data to a file and pass that file to yalpa's stdin:

```
yalpa.exe < my_audio.raw
```

Note: yalpa works in cmd, but not in PowerShell. Pipes seem to be handled differently there (see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504847/powershells-pipe-adds-linefeed)).

**The code:**

Disclaimer: I can not guarantee that this code is 100% bug-free, but I tested it on two different machines with Windows 7 and Windows 10 respectively. It was compiled and linked using the Visual Studio 2013 compiler. I was also able to compile it using g++ on Cygwin, but OpenAL failed at runtime because of problems with pulseaudio.

Feel free to edit and use my code.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#if defined _WIN32
#include <al.h>
#include <alc.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#else
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#endif

#if 0 || defined _DEBUG
#define AL_CHECK_ERROR(msg) (checkALError(msg))
#else
#define AL_CHECK_ERROR(msg)
#endif

const uint8_t numBuf = 3;
const ALsizei bufSize = 1000;
const ALenum format = AL_FORMAT_MONO8;
const ALsizei freq = 8000;
char readBuf[bufSize]; 

void checkALError(const char * msg)
{
    while (ALuint err = alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR)
        std::cerr << "Caught AL Error at " << msg << ": " << err << "\n";
}

ALsizei fillBufferFromStdin(ALuint buf)
{
    // read
    const ALsizei bytesRead = (ALsizei) fread(readBuf, sizeof(uint8_t), bufSize, stdin);
    // copy to OpenAL buffer
    alBufferData(buf, format, (void *) readBuf, bytesRead, freq);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("buffer data");
    return bytesRead;
}

void updateBuffers(ALuint src, ALuint bufs[numBuf])
{
    ALint srcState;
    do
    {
        // wait until a buffer is free
        ALint val = 0;
        do 
        {
            alGetSourcei(src, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &val);
            AL_CHECK_ERROR("get num processed");
            if (val > 0) break;
            // sleep for a quarter of the duration a buffer plays
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((bufSize / freq) * 1000 / 4));
        } while (true);
        while (val--)
        {
            // remove oldest buffer from queue and get its id
            ALuint buf;
            alSourceUnqueueBuffers(src, 1, &buf);
            AL_CHECK_ERROR("unqueue buffer");
            // fill buffer
            const ALsizei bytesRead = fillBufferFromStdin(buf);
            // add buffer to queue
            alSourceQueueBuffers(src, 1, &buf);
            AL_CHECK_ERROR("queue buffer");
            // if end of stdin was reached, return
            if (bytesRead < bufSize) return;
        }
        // check if source is still playing
        alGetSourcei(src, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &srcState);
    } while (AL_PLAYING == srcState);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "OpenAL test project\n";
    // set stdin to binary mode
#ifdef _WIN32
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
#else
    freopen(nullptr, "rb", stdin);
#endif

    // initialization: open default device
    ALCdevice * dev = alcOpenDevice(nullptr);
    // reset error state
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("open device");
    // create a context
    ALCcontext * context = alcCreateContext(dev, nullptr);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("create context");
    alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("activate context");
    // create buffers for audio streaming
    ALuint bufs[numBuf];
    alGenBuffers(numBuf, bufs);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("create buffer");
    // create source to play buffer
    ALuint src;
    alGenSources(1, &src);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("create source");
    
    // initially fill buffers
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numBuf; ++i) fillBufferFromStdin(bufs[i]);
    alSourceQueueBuffers(src, numBuf, bufs);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("queue buffer");
    // play source
    alSourcePlay(src);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("play");
    // fill buffers in loop
    updateBuffers(src, bufs);
    // when stream is read completely, wait until source stops playing
    ALint srcState;
    do
    {
        alGetSourcei(src, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &srcState);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    } while (AL_PLAYING == srcState);


    // delete source
    alDeleteSources(1, &src);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("delete source");
    // delete buffers
    alDeleteBuffers(numBuf, bufs);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("delete buffer");
    // destroy context
    alcDestroyContext(context);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("destroy context");
    // close device
    alcCloseDevice(dev);
    AL_CHECK_ERROR("close device");

    std::cout << "Exiting\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vlc and some command-line arguments I copy-pasted from the internet you are able to recreate aplay's functionality on windows.

```
audio.exe | vlc --demux=rawaud --rawaud-channels 2 --rawaud-samplerate 8000 -
```

Credit should go to [this post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=44726) and FreeER's answer.

Comment: where is the bitstream source parameter?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: it seems like there's isn't really a good solution, but another approximate-enough one that I found was to use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) with the following options to generate a .wav file:

```
./a.exe | sox -t raw -b 16 -e signed -r 8000 - test.wav
```

This creates a very large file very quickly, so don't let it run for too long. About 10 seconds on my machine (Intel i7 3.4GHz processor) generated about 2hrs of audio (~125KB).

Comment: Without knowing sox, you could tell it to output on `stdout` then pipe this to `head -c <bytes>` to limit the output to a number of bytes. `samples/second × bytes/channel/sample × channels × seconds = bytes`. You'll lose a few samples due to the header, but it's a quick and dirty method. Otherwise, `sox` has a command that will let you trim an input: `sox <options> - test.wav trim 0 60`, meaning it will skip 0 seconds and take 60 seconds from the input.

Answer (score 0):

the python module simleSound uses mciSendStringW on windows to play a sound file, on osx it runs afplay, on linux it runs aplay:  https://github.com/nekumelon/simpleSound/blob/main/simpleSound.py

you can use that to do a one liner for playing a sound.

`pip install simpleSound` to install the module

Answer (score 0):

For my minimalist audio player 2n (https://github.com/Canar/2n) I did a little footwork. Normally, 2n depends on something like pacat from Pulseaudio or aplay from ALSA to output; ffmpeg works here too. At some point, I plan to bring it to Windows. So I wrote a little shim. Haven't finished porting the rest of the program over, but the shim works for waveOut.

I compiled under Debian using mingw cross-compilation and then used wine to test it. I imagine it ought to work in a native Windows mingw environment but I dunno. I have not tested that.

Build like this, producing a.exe:
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc wo.c -lwinmm`

Execute like this:
`ffmpeg -i audio.file -f s16le - | a.exe`

```
/*wo.c*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BPS        16
#define RATE_      44100
#define CHAN_      2
#define BLK_N   8
#define BLK_LEN 16384

int main(){
    char buffer[BLK_N*BLK_LEN];
    char *buf[BLK_N];
    for (int i=0;i<BLK_N;i++)
        buf[i]=buffer+(i*BLK_LEN);

    WAVEFORMATEX wf;
    wf.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wf.nBlockAlign = ( wf.wBitsPerSample = BPS ) >> 3 * ( wf.nChannels = CHAN_ );
    wf.nAvgBytesPerSec = ( wf.nSamplesPerSec = RATE_ ) * wf.nBlockAlign;
    wf.cbSize = 0;

    WAVEHDR wh[BLK_N];
    for (int i=0;i<BLK_N;i++){
        wh[i].lpData = buf[i];
        wh[i].dwBufferLength = BLK_LEN;
        wh[i].dwFlags = WHDR_DONE;
        wh[i].dwLoops = 0;
    }

    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY); // required
    HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
    waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut,WAVE_MAPPER,&wf,0,0,CALLBACK_NULL);
    int ef;
    do {
        ef=0;
        for (int i=0;i<BLK_N;i++)
                if(wh[i].dwFlags & WHDR_DONE){
                        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut,&wh[i],sizeof(wh));
                        wh[i].dwBufferLength = fread(buf[i],1,BLK_LEN,stdin);
                        ef=wh[i].dwBufferLength<1;
                        waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut,&wh[i],sizeof(wh));
                        waveOutWrite(hWaveOut,&wh[i],sizeof(wh));
                        break;
                }
    } while (!ef);

    for (int i=0;i<BLK_N;i++) waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut,&wh[i],sizeof(wh));
    waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
    return 0;
}
```